# Is the following set a manifold?

Tags: calculus, smooth-manifolds

Show (using the implicit function theorem) that the following subset $$M:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\;|x^2+y^4+z^4=3\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{3}$$

Theorem: Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open  let $g:A\to \mathbb{R}^{p}$ be a differentiable function such that $g^{\prime}(x)$ has rank $p$ whenever $g(x)=0$. Then $g^{-1}(0)$ is an $n-p$ dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Solution.

Let $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^4+z^4-3$, denote $M=F^{-1}(0)$. Then for each $P=(x,y,z)\in M$ we have 
$$F^{\prime}(x,y,z)=\nabla F(x,y,z)=(2x,4y^3,4z^3)\neq 0$$

If $$\nabla F(x,y,z)=(2x,4y^3,4z^3)= 0$$ then $(x,y,z)=0$ and $F(x,y,z)=-3$ **which is a contradition to $F(x,y,z)=0$**
in other words $F^{\prime}(x,y,z)$ har always rank $1$. By the theorem $M$ is a manifold of $dim=2$

Is this solution correct? I have a question concerning the following part:

''$F(x,y,z)=-3$ **which is a contradition to $F(x,y,z)=0$**.''

So when $(x,y,z)=0$ then clearly $F(x,y,z)=0+0+0-3=-3$
in other words,: $F(x,y,z)=0$ is required by the theorem? and only then   $F^{\prime}(x,y,z)$ has rank $p$?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is correct.

The only point that can possibly satisfy $\nabla F(x, y, z) = 0$ is $(0, 0, 0)$, but this point isn't an element of $M$ to begin with. Thus, $M$ is a manifold per the theorem you quote.

Comment: Thank you Ayman. Why is $F(x,y,z)=-3$ is a contradition to $F(x,y,z)=0$? Is $F(x,y,z)=0$ required by the theorem?

Comment: "(...) such that $g′(x)$ has rank p whenever $g(x)=0$" - in our case, $F$ is $g$, so we are only concerned with points where $F$ is $0$.

Comment: @user124471 The set $M$ you're considering is the set of points that satisfy $F(x, y, z) = 0$. In other words, you only care about the points that satisfy $F(x, y, z) = 0$. And yes, the theorem you quote is applicable to $F^{-1}(0)$, which is another way of saying $F(x, y, z) = 0$.

Comment: Great, all is clear now. Thank you both. What if$$M:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\;|x^2-y^4-z^4=0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{3}$$ is the theorem also applicable?