# How to show that $n$ -dimensional sphere $S^{n}$ is a smooth manifold

Tags: calculus, smooth-manifolds

Let $S^{n}:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\;:|x|=1\}$, then $S^{n}$ is a smooth manifold. 
(Spivak ''Calculus on manifolds'' page 111)

Spivak's remark is ''note that $S^{n}=g^{-1}(0)$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $g(x)=|x|^2-1$. I guess, again I have to use the implicit function theorem and the fact that if (Spivak also p.111) $g:A\to \mathbb{R}^{p}$ is differentiable such that $g^{\prime}(x)$ has rank  $p$ whenever $g(x)=0$ then $g^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth manifold of dim $n-p$.

Here is the similar problem, using the very same theorem:
[Is the following set a manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799422/is-the-following-set-a-manifold/799427#799427)

So, in particular $M:=S^{n}=g^{-1}(0)$, and then should I find the differential of $g(x)$ and determine for which points $x\in S^{n}$ it's value is zero?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you should do that.

Comment: Notice that the codomain if the function $g$ is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the stereographic projections give an atlas for $\mathbb{S}_n$; you can verify by hand that the transition maps are smooth.

Comment: Thanks mathmax but I am not familar with concepts such as atlas, so I would like to stick to the procedure described in the theroem, I am a beginner in differential calculus.

Comment: Then you should use the quoted remark:  Differentiate $g:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $x\mapsto\vert x\vert-1=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i^2-1$ and verify that rank $g^\prime=1$ for $g (x)=0$

Comment: The codomain of $g$ is $R$.

Comment: @mathmax : $g^{\prime}(x)=2|x|\frac{x}{|x|}=2x$. Now I need to show that $g^{\prime}(x)\neq 0$ for any $x\in S^{n}$. If $g^{\prime}(x)=0$ then $x=0$ and then $g(x)=-1$ which contradicts $g(x)=0$ , does it mean that $g^{\prime}(x)$ has always rank $1$? But then, the sphere is a smooth manifold of $\text{dim}\;S^{n}=n+1-1=n$ Is this right?

Comment: Looks good to me. $g^\prime(x)\neq 0$ is another way of saying that rank $g>0$; because the dimension of the codomain of $g$ is $1$, the rank equals $1$.